# How to prevent Spring from adding base url again and again (Spring Security)

Tags: spring, hibernate, filter, spring-security, tiles

I've created an application using Spring, Hibernate, tiles, Spring security.

There are pages which can be accessed without logging in. And there are pages which can only be accessed after logging in(i.e. users with the role 'ROLE_USER'). "Account settings" is a page which can be accessed after logging in. When i hit the account settings url without logging in. It takes me directly to login screen. After logging, it redirects me to account settings page. It is the expected behavior. But the problem which i am facing is when i try to hit the link 'account setting' for the second time. It is adding one extra /user in front of the url and I am getting 404 error. How to prevent spring from prefixing user again and again. Even i tried 'redirect' but it didn't help. Your help is highly appreciated.

**URL**

http://localhost:8080/myapp/**user**/accountSettings (First time)
http://localhost:8080/myapp/**user/user**/accountSettings (Second time)

**spring-security.xml**

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
.....
```

**Link**

```
<a href="user/accountSettings">Account Setting</a>
```

**Controller Class**

```
@RequestMapping("/user/accountSettings")
public ModelAndView accountSettings() {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("accountSettings");
    return model;
}
```

**tiles.xml**

```
<definition name="accountSettings" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Account Settings" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/accountSettings.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the HTML link. You can try

`<a href="accountSettings">Account Setting</a>`

or

`<a href="/myapp/user/accountSettings">Account Setting</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hard-coding your context path, use this

`<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>`

`<a href="<c:url value='/user/accountSettings'/>">Account Settings</a>`

I'd recommend using hyphens in URLs though, like `account-settings`

Comment: Actually i didn't hard code. I used this

<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/user/accountSettings">Account Settings</a>

But your solutions is also working. What is the use of having hyphens in URL's. I am hearing this for the first time. Is there any advantage of using this. @Neil McGuigan